# change value in specific columns based on condition, without changing other values. in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, rscript

I have a dataframe with columns containing values 1-6, I want to change this to 1-3
What I want is: 1=1,2=1, 3=2, 4=2, 5=3, 6=3.
I want to change this in my columns named: `sub1.4`, `sub2.4`, `sub3.4`, `sub4.4`, `sub5.4`, `sub6.4`, `sub7.4`, `sub8.4`, `sub9.3`, `sub10.4`, `sub 11.4`, `sub 12.4`, `sub13.4`, `sub14.4`, `sub15.4`, `sub16.4`, `sub17.3`,  `sub18.4`,  `sub20.4`.

However, when I change the values of one, it will change that value when adjusting the following value. for example: I turn 5's into 3, and when I turn 3's into 2 it also changes the 'new' 3's to 2.

I want to change the current state of the dataframe to the above stated.

I tried:

```
     B_data1[B_data1 == 5] <- 3                    #turn all value 5 into 3 in B_data
        B_data1[B_data1 == 6] <- 3                 #turn all value 6 into 3 in B_data
        B_data1$sub1.4[B_data1$sub1.4<2] <- 1      #turn all value 2 into 1 in B_data$.. 'specifc column'
        B_data1$sub1.4[B_data1$sub1.4<3] <- 2      #turn all value 3 into 2 in B_data$.. 'specifc column'
        B_data1$sub1.4[B_data1$sub1.4<4] <- 2      #turn all value 4 into 2 in B_data$.. 'specifc column'
        ... 
#NOTE: value 5 and 6 are only present in the above (first alinea) stated columns, values 1-4 are also present in different columns of which I don't want to change the value of
```

This will result in a 'loop-problem', of also the new values changing.
How do I change the value of specific columns to different values, without changing it when changing different values?

Example dataset (this one has 1-6 in all columns, However mine dataset has 1-6 only in specific columns as stated above):

```
B_data1 <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 51, ncol = 41))
# Set the column names for the first column and items columns
colnames(B_data1) <- c("ID", paste(rep(paste0("sub", 1:20), each = 2), c("_1", "_2"), sep = ""))
# Fill the ID column with values 1 to 51
B_data1$ID <- 1:51
# Fill the item columns with random 0's and 1's
set.seed(123) # Set seed for reproducibility
B_data1[, 2:41] <- matrix(sample(c(1:6), size = 20 * 2 * 51, replace = TRUE), ncol = 40)
# Show the resulting data frame
B_data1
```

***edit:***

I solved this by the following code:

```
B_data1[,c("sub1.4","sub2.4", "sub3.4", "sub4.4", "sub5.4", "sub6.4", "sub7.4", "sub8.4", "sub9.3", "sub10.4", "sub11.4", "sub12.4", "sub13.4", "sub14.4",
           "sub15.4", "sub16.4", "sub17.3", "sub18.4", "sub20.4")]<- ifelse(is.na(B_data1$sub1.4), NA, 
                                                                            ifelse(B_data1$sub1.4 %in% c(1,2), 1, 
                                                                                   ifelse(B_data1$sub1.4 %in% c(3,4), 2, 3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

While R provides many different ways to rename variable values in general (You can read [here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html) about the data type "factor"), in your case the easiest solution probably is to divide the integers by 2 and apply the `ceiling()` function:

```
recode <- function(column) {
  ceiling(column/2)
  }

table(items$item1_1, recode(items$item1_1))
#      1  2  3
#   1  9  0  0
#   2  8  0  0
#   3  0 11  0
#   4  0  6  0
#   5  0  0 10
#   6  0  0  7
```